# Griffiths and Harris $\mu=\mathcal{H}(\mu)+dd^*G(\mu)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, complex-manifolds

Griffith and Harris state on page $116$ that for a closed form $\mu$ on a Kahler manifold of type $(p,q)$ we have
$$\mu=\mathcal{H}(\mu)+dd^*G(\mu)$$
Here
$$\mathcal{H}:\Omega^{p,q}(M)\to\mathcal{H}^{p,q}(M)$$
is the projection onto the harmonic part, using the Hodge theorem. $G:\Omega^{p,q}(M)\to\Omega^{p,q}(M)$ is the Green's operator.

However, here they seem to use that first, since the metric is Kahler
$$\mu=\mathcal{H}(\mu)+\Delta_{\bar\partial}G(\mu)=\mathcal{H}(\mu)+\Delta_{d}G(\mu)$$
Then they must expand:
$$\Delta_dG(\mu)=(dd^*+d^*d)G(\mu)=dd^*G(\mu)+d^*dG(\mu)$$
And now they seems to use
$$dG=Gd$$
to get rid of the term $d^*dG(\mu)$. However, the Hodge theorem only gives us
$$\bar\partial G=G\bar\partial, \bar\partial^* G=G\bar\partial^*$$
So I don't see how we can conclude that $dG=Gd$?

Comment: What do the expressions $\mathcal{H}(\mu)$ and $G(\mu)$ mean?

Comment: @msteve sorry, added it in the edit.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Green's operator is real, so complex conjugating $\bar{\dd}G = G\bar{\dd}$ gives $\dd G = G\dd$; consequently,
$$
dG = (\dd + \bar{\dd})G = G(\dd + \bar{\dd}) = Gd.
$$